# Decrypting Windows Crypto API RSA Ciphertext With OpenSSL

Tags: winapi, cryptography, openssl, endianness

I have created a C++ program that encrypts some bytes with a RSA 2048 key.

The output of the program is 256 bytes and everything seems to work fine.

However I've been completely unable to figure out how to decrypt this with openssl.

I've been told that I might need to reverse the byte order so it becomes big endian but it doesn't seem to help. (I assume reversing the bytes order means turning 1F 02 C8 into F1 20 8C etc.)

I'm mainly getting the following error from openssl.

openssl rsautl -in output.bin -inkey privatekey -decrypt
rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_2:block type is not 02:rsa_pk1.c:190:

Here is a code snippet of my encryption for anyone that interested (I've tried it with final as true also)

```
BYTE crapBuffer[1200] = {0x33,0x1F,0x22,0x34,0x33,0x1F,0x22,0x34,0x33,0x1F,0x22,0x34,0x33,0x1F,0x22,0x34,0x33,0x1F,0x22,0x34};
DWORD dataLen = 20;
CryptEncrypt(publicKey,0,false,0,(BYTE *)crapBuffer,&dataLen,1200);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Comment: First of all, little endian to big endian, is not what you did, you reversed bytes! That's wrong. In conversion, 0x1F02C800 becomes 0x00C8021F. Now, in addition to that, instead of what you put in that crapbuffer, show more details about public and private key you used between windows API and openssl. Are you sure you are using proper public and private key?

Comment: Be careful of Windows `PRIVATEKEYBLOB` (I think that's what its called). Its actually endian swapped, so you get the entire array in little endian rather than big endian (big endian is used nearly everywhere else and by other libraries).